# Experiment regarding myopic correction by a manipulation of fingers?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, home-experiment, vision

Here is a small experiment my tutor once told us for just amusement. It works for myopic people at least, and can be a good check to see if you have myopia.

> With your naked eye, ("remove the spectacles" for myopic spectacle
>   wearers) see a considerably distant object (a few meters). It should
>   be a bit blurred and unclear if you have myopia. Then, using your
>   two thumbs and first fingers of both hands, create a tiny square in
>   between. Using a single eye, look through the square. For a large
>   square, the image is still blurred. But as you purse your fingers
>   tightly and reduce the dimensions of the space between, you will
>   eventually reach a point when the image comes in perfect focus. The
>   image is perfectly clear as you would see it with spectacles. For an object 1-2m away, the square needs to be much smaller than that in the picture.

[image: Not my hands][image: Not my hands]

This works for almost any myopic person. Why does it work? Does diffraction come into play? If it does, I don't see how that can adequately refract rays to act as a lens?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not diffraction. It's because you increase the depth of field by reducing the aperture.

Basically, the more concentraded the light is, the better you see a defocused images.

See this question: [Why does aperture size affect depth of field in photography?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83303/)

Comment: aka. squinting.

Comment: By putting a small aperture in front of your eye you are in effect making a [pinhole camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera). One of the answers to the question jinawee linked includes ray diagrams showing how a pinhole camera gives a sharp image.

Comment: From what I read, the sharpness is caused by elimination of various spherical aberrations. But in case of a myopic person, the normal blurring is due to the extra power of the eye-lens to converge rays. How is that corrected by this pin-hole effect

Comment: @SatwikPasani _sharpness is caused
by elimination of
various spherical
aberrations._ This effect is not important in the eye case and not much in the camera case.